# How to convert b'\xc8\x00' to float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, type-conversion, decode

I actually get a value (`b'\xc8\x00'`) from a temperature sensor. I want to convert it to a float value. Is it right, that I need to decode it?

Here is my function:

```
def ToFloat(data):
    s = data.decode('utf-8')
    print(s)
    return s
```

But when I try to compile it, I get the error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: What temperature, approximately, do you expect the value to be in the end? There are a million ways to convert two characters into a number, and it would help narrow it down if we knew if your thermometer was in an oven or in your living room or in Antarctica.

Comment: Compile ? In python ? What do you think str.decode is supposed to do ? What is the string you seem trying to convert to a float ?

Comment: What float value does `b'\xc8\x00'` represent? What kind of floating point representation is it? It's not a common IEEE format which would require at least 4 bytes of data, so just two bytes isn't enough. If you know the representation, then the `struct` module would seem to be the one to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be having packed bytes not unicode objects. Use `struct.unpack`:

```
In [3]: import struct
In [4]: struct.unpack('h', b'\xc8\x00')[0]
Out[4]: 200
```

Format `h` specifies a short value (2 bytes). If your temperature values will always be positive, you can use `H` for unsigned short:

```
import struct

def to_float(data):
    return float(struct.unpack('H', data)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `ToFloat()` is a bit irritating as it returns a float but interpretes the data as integer values. If the bytes are representing a float, it would be necessary to know in which format the float is packed into these two bytes (usually float takes more than two bytes).

```
data = b'\xc8\x00'
def ToFloat(data):
    byte0 = int(data[0])
    print(byte0)
    byte1 = int(data[1])
    print(byte1)
    number = byte0 + 256*byte1
    print(number)
    return float(number)
```

returns: **200.0** what seems to be reasonable. If not, just see what the data mean and process accordingly.